# Send XSSFWorkbook in response entity (No serializer found for class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale)

Tags: java, rest, apache-poi, response, xssf

I am trying to send XSSFWorkbook Object in response entity and getting the following error:

```
[Servlet Error]-[rest-servlet]: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook["ctworkbook"]->org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookImpl["fileVersion"]->org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFileVersionImpl["xmlLocale"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.failForEmpty(StdSerializerProvider.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:587)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1145)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:520)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

And this is my java controller method :

```
@POST
    @Path("/excel")
    public Response getExcel() {
        try {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(this.classname.getExcelObject()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ExceptionHandler.error(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried to create getters and setters for a new class which has only XSSFWorkbook object and then was returning the object of that class. But that doesn't work.

How can I return Apache poi XSSFWorkbook object in response entity.

I don't want to support user download of this object but want to use this later and hence I am not using HTTPServletResponse headers for download.

Comment: The error appears to be caused by an attempt to JSON serialize an XSSFWorkbook - this won't work. You need to call the write(OutputStream) method on the XSSFWorkbook to save the data as xlsx format binary.

Comment: @PJ Fanning can you please provide some code example. I don't want the user to download the file and I don't want to write the file to any temporary location. I just want this for later use